# init var with swift using SpriteKit?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

How to correctly init with swift using SpriteKit?

This compiles but I get a error once the simulator starts running. "swift_reportUnimplementedInitializer"

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var paddlePositionUpdate:CGPoint

    init(paddlePositionUpdate:CGPoint){
    self.paddlePositionUpdate = CGPoint.zeroPoint
    super.init()
}
}
```

Comment: I figured out what I could use to hold a value. I just made a dictionary. Not pretty but it works!!! THanks Roshan!!!  var gameSettings:Dictionary = ["paddlePositionUpdate":CGPoint.zeroPoint]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The designated inititaliser for `SKScene` is `init(size)` where `size` is the size of your scene. You have attempted to use `init()` which does not exist.

You can see the exact method signature if you Cmd+click on `SKScene`...

EDIT: Try something like

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    var paddlePositionUpdate: CGPoint

    init(size: CGSize, paddlePosition: CGPoint = CGPoint.zeroPoint){
        paddlePositionUpdate = paddlePosition
        super.init(size)
    }
}
```

A scene should be initialised with a size...

Comment: maybe I am going about this the wrong way. All I need is to use point variable as a place holder for the movement a paddler object.

Comment: breakoutIphone/GameScene.swift: 11: 11: fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer           class GameScene: SKScene {
    
    var paddlePositionUpdate: CGPoint
    
    init(size: CGSize, paddlePosition: CGPoint = CGPoint.zeroPoint){
        paddlePositionUpdate = paddlePosition
        super.init(size:self.size)
    }
}

Comment: I think I was getting a bug. Not everything is work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @masters3d I do not understand why you use 'super.init(size:self.size)' in your comments. Shouldn't it be 'super.init(size:size)' ?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem when replacing a scene with another one using

```
let gameScene = GameScene(size: self.size)
self.view.presentScene(gameScene)
```

And I kept getting 2 errors about initialization:

```
// Error #1
'GameScene' is not constructible with '(size: @lvalue CGSize)'
// Error #2
Class 'GameScene' has no initializers
```

To fix error #1, just replace `GameScene(size: self.size)` with `GameScene.sceneWithSize(self.size)`

Error #2 seems to be affected by how the property is initialized. For example, if I wrote:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

var test: CGPoint
// ...
}
```

Error #2 was still there. But if I replaced `var test: CGPoint` with `var test: CGPoint!` , `var test = CGPoint(0,0)` , or any other lines may give `test` a certain value, Error #2 was gone. I searched the guide book but found lots of classes using lines like `var test: CGPoint`. And here I got confused.

**It maybe a common problem for Swift beginners and I hope my temporary solution helps.**